# Using GetPrivateProfileString from kernel32.dll

Tags: c#, uwp, kernel32

I'm working on an UWP app meant to be running on a Raspberry Pi. I need to read data stored in .ini files - I know Microsoft would like me to use xml, but I am required to use ini.

I've succesfully used GetPrivateProfileString (following this : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1966/An-INI-file-handling-class-using-C) to read values from an ini file with a "standard" C# project.

However, this does not seem to be working on an UWP C# project. I don't have any error, simply that nothing happens if I try to read or write using the kernel32 functions.

What is happening ? Is it still possible to use these functions in an UWP app ? If not, will I have to write an ini-handling class myself ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724353(v=vs.85).aspx) says:

> Note  This function is provided only for compatibility with 16-bit
>   Windows-based applications. Applications should store initialization
>   information in the registry.

I assume that the function is not avaliable on your target platform. You have to read and parse the INI file yourself.

Comment: I've seen conflicting opinions on this - one half advises to ignore this comment (just search for "c# read ini" on google, you'll only see kernel32.dll based solutions), the other advises to forget about using these functions because of the comment. I'd happily use a non-outdated ini API if I could

Comment: [This page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/mt186421%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) lists all possible api functions for UWP apps. `GetPrivateProfileString` is not there so you have to do it yourself.

Comment: I successfully used GetUsername from advapi32.dll (http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32.getusername) even though it isn't listed there, but this was probably a rare exception. I'll make my own parser then, with blackjack and hookers.